# Block port on boot2docker vm on virtualmachine

Tags: networking, python, docker

I have [Boot2Docker](http://boot2docker.io) image running in `VirtualBox` on my mac. I use [Kitematic](https://kitematic.com) to run `docker` on my Mac.

I have `activemq` docker running, on port `32769` in `boot2docker` vm. I have application running which connect to `activemq` on port `32769`.

My application randomly gives error as below.

```
[INFO] stompest.async.listener: Disconnected: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.
[ERROR] stompest.async.listener: Disconnect failure: Unexpected connection loss [Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.]
[INFO] stompest.async.protocol: Connecting to 10.4.252.37:61613 ...
[-] Starting factory <stompest.async.protocol.StompFactory instance at 0x231afc8>
[WARNING] stompest.async.protocol: Could not connect to 10.4.252.37:61613 [Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.]
[INFO] stompest.async.protocol: Delaying connect attempt for 10 ms
[Uninitialized] Stopping factory <stompest.async.protocol.StompFactory instance at 0x117e6c8>
[INFO] stompest.async.protocol: Connecting to 192.168.99.100:32769 ...
[-] Starting factory <stompest.async.protocol.StompFactory instance at 0x7f8ca428ec68>
[-] Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-05-31 10:12:20+0000 [-] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stompest-2.1.2-py2.7.egg/stompest/util/__init__.py", line 16, in __checkattr

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator

--- <exception caught here> ---
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stompest.async-2.1.1-py2.7.egg/stompest/async/client.py", line 275, in subscribe

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stompest-2.1.2-py2.7.egg/stompest/protocol/session.py", line 125, in subscribe

stompest.error.StompProtocolError: Already subscribed [id=test]
```

To reproduce this, I have to block port `32769` and unblock again so [`stompest`](https://github.com/nikipore/stompest) will try to connect again and create same error.

I check `ifconfig` on `boot2docker` vm, but it randomly create port.

Is there any way to block port and unblock again ?